# Development WordPress admin link redirecting to live site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to make new changes to a WordPress site I have. So I copied all files and exported to new development sub-domain. Made new database for the sub-domain and imported the database from live site.

Live site: http://mysite.com

Dev site: http://dev.mysite.com

Seems to be working, but all nav links still point to live site. And main issue is when I go to http://dev.mysite.com/wp-admin, I get redirected to live site. This is link I'm getting redirected to:

http://mysite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysite.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There is a canonical resource for this issue: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: When I move WordPress sites across domains I usually just download the whole database as SQL, edit it with a text editor to manually replace all references, then import it to the new site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answers above are correct, most of the time editing the 'home' and 'site' url in the wp_options table will do the trick, however sometimes it's necessary to run a search and replace on the database (use at your own risk):

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

This has worked very well for me in the past.

Also, updating your permalink settings by going to Settings->Permalinks and just clicking 'Save' will often fix url problems.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, since you do not have access to wp-admin for updating permalinks, you can try this:

Edit `wp-config.php` and add this:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

where http://example.com is your site url.

Directly after "That's all, stop editing!" insert this line:

`define('RELOCATE',true);`

Then, navigate to http://example.com/wp-login.php

Please let me know if that works or not.

Comment: I've changed home and siteurl. Still no luck. Also tried using interconnectit search and replace tool. Most site links seem to be working correctly going to the dev site, but wp-admin is still giving a 404 and displaying this link: http://dev.mysite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysite.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: Did you re-save your permalinks settings? Are you using the same permalinks as the live site?

Comment: Can't get into wp-admin. I get the 404. So no way to get to settings > permalinks.

Comment: Updating answer with some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Not sure if it would've worked or not.. the issue was when I was copying the site, it missed wp-login file. So this caused the 404. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your second solution worked for me. Not sure what happened, I've always used the solution you described first and it only failed this time.

Answer (score 0):

in your wp_options table, edit the first few records (sorted asc by ID) and edit them to have the correct URL.

You can also identify other options by using a SQL similar to SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_value like '%mysite.com%'

Comment: Edited wp_options table. I've set the siteurl to dev.mysite.com, but when going to dev.mysite.com/wp-admin I get a 404 now. And this is the link showing: http://dev.mysite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysite.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Wordpress database for the wp_options table.

In the option_name column, find the "siteurl" row.  Change the option_value in that row to http://dev.mysite.com .

Look again in the option_name column for the row with "home" in it. Change the option_value in that row to http://dev.mysite.com .

That should do it.

Comment: I've changed home and siteurl. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Wp-login was missing from the dev site. For some reason, it didn't copy over. So it caused the 404 when trying to access wp-admin.