# WP Redirection to live site

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have problem with my redirection at local wordpress. So far I changed db records (*site_url, home*) in **wp_options** table. It's work for http://localhost (there before redirect to live domain site), but when I type //localhost/wp-admin its redirect to live domain page.

In network i see 301 status with redirection to location with live page.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192758/development-wordpress-admin-link-redirecting-to-live-site?rq=1)

Comment: Did you check you .htaccess file?

Comment: have you it fix ?